# Should I sell my magic items, or salvage them?

Tags: diablo-iii

So far (I just started Act 2), grey items sell for almost nothing: usually 3-6 gold pieces.

Magic items can sell for considerably more at this level.  150 gold may not seem like a lot in the big scheme of things, but it is much better than 3-6 gold!

However, I've been salvaging everything magical instead of selling it.  Is this a mistake?  So far I've level my blacksmith to the point where most of what he makes is powerful enough that I have to gain several levels before I can even use it.  I also have a lot of [subtle essences](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/subtle-essence) and a decent supply of of [fallen teeth](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/fallen-tooth).

Am I better off selling some of my magic items, instead of salvaging everything?  Is there a specific vendor-price I should use as a guideline (i.e. "everything that sells for more than *x* gold should be vendored")?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Watch the auction house.**

Right now, crafting materials are selling for *substantially* less gold than all but the worst low level blue items. You'll get far better results selling your blue items and buying Essences from the AH.

For example, current market value for normal mode mats is 20g for Subtle Essence and 45g for Fallen Teeth. So any item worth more than 25g, I sell. If its worth less than 25, I gamble for a shot at a tooth.

Answer (score 2):

*Lets split this.*

### What can I do with an magic item?

- Sell in the NPC
- Savage into material
- Trade with a friend
- Sell it on AH

### Now lets see what are the pros and cons about it.

**Sell a magic item in the NPC**

Magic items worth more gold in the NPC that the normal items, if you want to farm some gold with low level items, you can go for it.

**Savage into material**

Savaging you will get craft-materials, where you can create a better item for you. Also the craft-material is marketable in the AH, so depending on the item (and a little of your luck), you can get more gold by selling the craft-material instead of the item on a NPC.

**Trade with a friend**

You can link a item by open the chat, holding <kbd>shift</kbd> and <kbd>left-click</kbd> in the item. So you can show for your friends. Maybe one of them want it, and have something you want too. Easy trade, win-win, friendly...

**Sell it on AH**

As always, you need some luck on AH and judgment. You can make a little fortune with just **one** item, but you can also use lots of items to achieve that. Check AH to see what's going on there, what're the Most Valuable Item, what people are looking for. With this, you can make good money.

---

Now, with all that said, I advise you this.

> Check AH and RMAH, see if the need more the item or more the
> craft-material. If none are good, check if you need some craft-item.
> If not, check with your friends if they have something to trade. And
> by last sell it on NPC.

Answer (score 2):

**Depends on item level (and AH materials prices)**

For items below level 60, the materials you get from salvaging currently sell for much less than you would get for selling the item to a vendor. So you are better off vendoring the item and buying any materials you need for crafting from the AH. Also has the nice benefit of not having to store materials.

However, level 60+ maigcal/rare items will generate exquisite essence, which lately sells for around 1700 - 2200 gold. This is probably more than the vendor would give you. You might also get an iridescent tear that sells for 500 - 750ish (yeah I know it should be worth more since they are more rare, but demand is also a lot lower). Finally, there's even a chance that the level 60+ item produces Fiery Brimstone, which sells for 55k - 60k. Alas, patch 1.0.3 made this chance even smaller, though they did not reveal what the % chance is.

Answer (score 0):

Salvage. The weapons and armor you create early on will usually last you past level 10. The crafted items will usually have more affixes than random drops.

The materials to craft you accumulate will eventually allow you to create Rare (yellow) and even Legendary (orange) quality items. With a typical Magic (blue) quality item from a random drop, the materials you get from salvaging are worth more (on the AH, at least for now) than if you sold the item to a NPC.

Depending on the affixes, you can also sell the crafted items on the AH for a better price as well. Items with high movement speed and MF affixes are selling quite well right now.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest going with Salvaging. The items that you can smith will generally be more interesting to what you can find in the shop. This is not always the case, but in general you will have enough cash on hand from the other sales and picking up gold for when that happens allowing you to build up crafting materials for when you might want to create a handful of objects to get the right random enchantments that will help you out.